# Is there an algorithm for computing planar embeddings for non-biconnected graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Every algorithm I've found so far begins by computing st numberings, which in turn requires a biconnected graph in order to work with an arbitrary  vertex pair (s, t). In the following graph, edges [A, B], [F, G] and [H, I] violate the i < j < k property of an st numbering:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQmju.png

It can obviously be planar, but how is the embedding computed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate the graph into biconnected components.  Find an embedding of each biconnected component.  Join the biconnected components together at the appropriate vertices, scaling if necessary to fit the components inside regions.